# Control the number of categories to display

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm new around here. I'm having a problem, I have a page where many categories are displayed, and when I add them to the home footer, it shows me all of them. There are so many that it doesn't look good in the house, I just want to show one line.

The code that calls the categories and subcategories is this:

```
<?php foreach ($getCategories as $item): ?>
        <div>

            <ul class="ul-nav ul-nav-default">
                    <li class="ul-nav-header"><a class="ul-text-secondary ul-text-capitalize" href="<?php echo $urlPath->search(['category' => $item['category_slug']]); ?>"><?php echo echoOutput($item['category_title']); ?></a></li>
                    <?php $getSubCategories = getSubCategories($connect, $item['category_id']); ?>
                    <?php foreach ($getSubCategories as $item): ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $urlPath->search(['subcategory' => $item['subcategory_slug']]); ?>"><?php echo echoOutput($item['subcategory_title']); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>

            </ul>

        </div>
```

How can I do so that only less quantity appears, is it possible?

Thank you so much!

I hope I can receive help, so I can finish my project.

Find help for my project, I don't know how to move forward with this problem in my code

Comment: Yes, anything is possible if you try it. In this case you could just use a counter to check how many you've processed. If you reach the predefined limit, stop processing. e.g. using a `for` loop instead of `foreach` can achieve this easily, or you can use a separate counter variable and then `break;` the loop when it reaches the specified value.

Comment: If you literally just want _one_ result, then you don't even need a loop - just access the first element of the array and you're done.

Comment: @ADyson No need for `for`. `foreach ($getCategories as $i => $item) { if ($i > $limit) break; ... }`

Comment: You could also just remove them from `$getCategories`: `$getCategories = array_slice($getCategories, 0, $limit);`

Comment: And if the categories come from a database query, you can use `LIMIT` in the query to specify the maximum number to return.

Comment: Thank you all, how would the code look, because I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Barmar gave you worked examples already. Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's just that from this code that I have now, I don't know how it should look with the new one. I tried yes, but it gives me an error.

Original: <?php foreach ($getCategories as $item): ?>
        <div>
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default">
                    <li class="uk-nav-header"><a class="uk-text-secondary uk-text-capitalize" href="<?php echo $urlPath->search(['category' => $item['category_slug']]); ?>"><?php echo echoOutput($item['category_title']); ?></a></li>

Comment: [Edit] your question to show precisely what you tried, based on the suggestions, and explain what error you got, please - then we can see where any misunderstanding might have arisen. Adding a $limit variable and testing its value should not be a particularly difficult task, even for a relative novice

Comment: Add Limit but I don't know if it goes there... I know more about design, I'm asking because I don't know much about programming, that's why I'm looking for help from you. Here what I did: https://ibb.co/HF239wz

Comment: Ok. But we're not a teaching service. We do expect that you have at least some foundational knowledge, so you can then apply the information you're given to your situation.

Comment: Thanks anyway... very bad vibes, it's not the answer I expected, I'm sure because I'm a woman they won't help me.

Comment: Lol we have no way of knowing that. Anyway there are plenty of solutions in the duplicate question (in the blue box above) showing you how to limit the number of times you loop through an array. Where an answer to a particular question already exists, we generally don't need to repeat it